# Ncurses and ostream class method?

Tags: c++

This might be a dumb question but I'll give it a shot.

Is there a way to have a class method that takes an ostream object as a parameter output to an Ncurses window?

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having? But yes I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this. I don't know much about ncurses though.

Comment: I have a huge class hierarchy that has print functions for each class with a prototype: Print(ostream& out); I would like to somehow call the function and the output end up in an Ncurses window. Is an ostringsream considered an ostream? If so I could call it passing in the stringstream and then use the stringstream to create a string and use that with the printw function of ncurses. Seems like a LOT of extra work though...

Comment: How do you access the ncurses window from your C++ program? You may be able to redirect the output from the `std::ostream` object to it.

Comment: Can you show your code please? Then I could possibly help you fix it. Yes, a `stringstream` is considered an `ostream`.

Comment: I haven't written anything other than the class hierarchy. I had to write it to a certain specification. I was just planning on doing an ncurses frontend for my own sake as a test driver so I could have windows within the console keeping updated output from various classes. A `stringstream` being considered an `ostream` answers my question. I can pass in a `stringstream` then use that to create a `string` and pass the string into the ncurses `printw()` for the given window. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 4):

First, we should leverage std::streambuf.  Here is a very simple example that just redirects std::cout to a simple printer

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <iostream>

class ncursesbuf: public std::streambuf {
public:
  ncursesbuf() {}
  virtual int overflow(int c) {
    printf("'%d'\n", c);
  }
};

class ncurses_stream : public std::ostream {
public:
  ncursesbuf tbuf_;
  std::ostream &src_;
  std::streambuf * const srcbuf_;

  ncurses_stream(std::ostream &o) : src_(o), srcbuf_(o.rdbuf()), std::ostream(&tbuf_) {
    o.rdbuf(rdbuf());
  }

  ~ncurses_stream() {
    src_.rdbuf(srcbuf_);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << "hello world\n";
  {
    ncurses_stream foo(std::cout);
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
  }
  std::cout << "back to original state\n";
  return 0;
}
```

We can then modify this to use ncurses

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>

class ncursesbuf: public std::streambuf {
public:
  ncursesbuf() {}
  virtual int overflow(int c) {
    printw("%c", c);
  }
};

class ncurses_stream : public std::ostream {
public:
  ncursesbuf tbuf_;
  std::ostream &src_;
  std::streambuf * const srcbuf_;

  ncurses_stream(std::ostream &o) : src_(o), srcbuf_(o.rdbuf()), std::ostream(&tbuf_) {
    o.rdbuf(rdbuf());
  }

  ~ncurses_stream() {
    src_.rdbuf(srcbuf_);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  /* ncurses setup */
  initscr();

  ncurses_stream foo(std::cout);
  std::cout << "hello world\n";
  refresh();
  sleep(5);
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```